# Node JS - Data Stream from S3 Bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, stream

i'm developing a software that provide direct download to my S3 bucket in Node JS.

I have develop the following code:

```
const stream = s3.getObject(getParams).createReadStream();

stream.on("error", (err) => {
 res.send(err);
});

res.setHeader("Content-disposition", `attachment; filename=${path.basename(req.params[ 0 ])}`);
stream.pipe(res);
```

and it works!

But if the file doesn't exist, the download will start and this is wrong (it contains the error message).

Where is the best place to put the Header? in a way to set it only if the file exist?

I have try several events like `on("data")` or `on("end")` but it doesn't works as expected.

After that, i need to close the stream after this operation?